# how to refresh list of data changed by component

Tags: reactjs

Description - I'm pulling a list of **Material** data from firestore and displaying it as a table. I've added a modal to add a **Material** to the database.

Problem - The refresh method I'm passing to the modal, `refreshList()` isn't refreshing the list of **Material**s on the Materials page. I'm quite certain the refresh method works—it's the same one I use to pull all Materials from firestore. what did I do wrong?

Here's the AddMaterialModal.

```
import { FC, useContext, useState } from "react";
import { ProjectContext } from "../../context/ProjectContext";
import MaterialService from "../../services/materialService";
import { Material } from "../../services/orgTypes";
import { randomString } from "../../utils/utils";
import AddEditTextModal from "./AddEditTextModal";
interface AddMaterialsModalProps {
  editting?: boolean;
  setOpenModal: (bool: boolean) => void;
  selectedMaterial?: Material;
  refreshList?: () => void;
}

const AddMaterialModal: FC<AddMaterialsModalProps> = ({
  editting,
  setOpenModal,
  selectedMaterial,
  refreshList,
}) => {
  const idTemp = randomString(20);
  const projectContext = useContext(ProjectContext);
  const [newMaterial] = useState<Material>({
    material: "material",
    actualquantity: "actualquantity",
    size: "size",
    id: idTemp,
    description: "description",
    type: "type",
    unit: "unit",
    quantity: "quantity",
  });
  const materialService = new MaterialService(
    projectContext.selectedProject.id
  );
  const createNewMaterial = () => {
    materialService.updateCreateGlobalMaterial(newMaterial);
    if (refreshList != undefined) {
      refreshList();
      setOpenModal(false);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="flex flex-col gap- 2 w-full h-fit ">
        {//input some material data here.}
      </div>
      <div className="flex justify-center align-center">
        <button
          onClick={createNewMaterial}
          className=" w-fit px-6  py-2.5 mt-6 bg-flowius-blue text-white font-medium text-lg leading-tight uppercase rounded shadow-md hover:bg-blue-400 hover:shadow-lg focus:bg-cyan-400 focus:shadow-lg focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 active:bg-blue-500 active:shadow-lg
            transition duration-150 ease-in-out"
        >
          {editting ? "UPDATE" : "ADD +"}
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddMaterialModal;
```

And here's the main Materials page.

```
import { FC, useCallback, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import DataTable from "react-data-table-component";
import { ProjectContext } from "../context/ProjectContext";
import { Material } from "../services/orgTypes";
import Loader from "../components/Loader";
import MaterialIcon from "../components/MaterialIcon";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import MaterialService from "../services/materialService";
import Modal from "../components/modal/Modal";
import AddMaterialModal from "../components/modal/AddMaterialModal";

interface Selected {
  allSelected: boolean;
  selectedCount: number;
  selectedRows: Material[];
}

export const formatDate = (date: Date) => {
  const month = date.toLocaleString("en-us", { month: "long" });
  const year = date.getFullYear();
  const day = date.getDate();
  return `${day} ${month} ${year}`;
};

const Materials: FC = () => {
  const [materials, setMaterials] = useState<Material[]>([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState<Selected>();
  const projectContext = useContext(ProjectContext);
  const { id } = projectContext.selectedProject;
  const materialService = new MaterialService(id);

  const pullMaterials = useCallback(async () => {
    if (!id) return;
    const materials = await materialService.getProjectMaterials();
    setMaterials(materials);
    setLoading(false);
  }, [id]);
  const [openAddMaterialModal, setOpenAddMaterialModal] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    pullMaterials();
  }, [pullMaterials]);
  const columns = [
    {
      name: "Material",
      selector: (row: Material) => row.material,
      sortable: true,
    },
    {
      name: "Description",
      selector: (row: Material) => row.description,
      sortable: true,
    },
    {
      name: "Size",
      selector: (row: Material) => row.size,
      sortable: true,
    },
    {
      name: "Unit",
      selector: (row: Material) => row.unit,
      sortable: true,
    },
    {
      name: "Actual Quantity",
      selector: (row: Material) => row.actualquantity,
      sortable: true,
    },
  ];
  const deleteSelected = async () => {
    if (!selected) return;
    const { selectedRows } = selected;
    materialService.deleteGlobalMaterial(selectedRows);
    toast.success(`${selectedRows.length} Items deleted`);
    pullMaterials();
    setSelected(undefined);
  };

  return (
    <div className="m-2 w-full">
      <div className="flex text-flowius-blue text-xl flex-row justify-between my-1">
        <button
          className="bg-flowius-blue text-base text-white p-2 rounded-md"
          onClick={() => {
            setOpenAddMaterialModal(true);
          }}
        >
          Add Material
        </button>
      </div>
      {(selected?.selectedCount ?? 0) > 0 && (
        <MaterialIcon
          className="cursor-pointer "
          onClick={deleteSelected}
          icon="delete"
        />
      )}
      {loading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : (
        <DataTable
          selectableRows={true}
          paginationRowsPerPageOptions={[50, 100, 150]}
          paginationPerPage={50}
          onSelectedRowsChange={setSelected}
          pagination={true}
          columns={columns}
          data={materials}
          defaultSortAsc={true}
          defaultSortFieldId="Material"
        />
      )}
      {setOpenAddMaterialModal && (
        <Modal
          open={openAddMaterialModal}
          close={() => {
            setOpenAddMaterialModal(false);
          }}
          title={"Add Material"}
          className={""}
        >
          <AddMaterialModal
            editting={false}
            setOpenModal={setOpenAddMaterialModal}
            refreshList={pullMaterials}
          />
        </Modal>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Materials;
```

Comment: Do you think the `id` in `pullMaterials` gets set to some falsy value

Comment: @Azzy no. I checked. It's the same project id, and refreshing the page manually will show the updated Material list (with the one I just added included). The only issue is that it doesn't happen automatically. I needed the modal to close, and the list to update.

Comment: I see the useCallBack has a dependency of `id` . Something weird may or may not be happening there since the ID isn't going to be changing. I don't really see the need to wrap the get req in a useCallback since it's not really doing anything intensive. Try removing it and just have a regular async fn that get's the data.